# Why enclose actions returned by Redux action creators in brackets?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm trying to understand Redux' `todos` example (https://redux.js.org/introduction/examples#todos), which contains the following `actions/index.js`:

```
let nextTodoId = 0
export const addTodo = text => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  id: nextTodoId++,
  text
})

export const setVisibilityFilter = filter => ({
  type: 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER',
  filter
})

export const toggleTodo = id => ({
  type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
  id
})

export const VisibilityFilters = {
  SHOW_ALL: 'SHOW_ALL',
  SHOW_COMPLETED: 'SHOW_COMPLETED',
  SHOW_ACTIVE: 'SHOW_ACTIVE'
}
```

It is not entirely clear to me why the objects returned by `addTodo`, `setVisibilityFilter`, and `toggleTodo` are enclosed in round brackets, like `({...})`, instead of just the curly braces, `{...}`?

I've read in places like http://jamesknelson.com/javascript-return-parenthesis/ that the brackets are useful to prevent Javascript from prematurely inserting semicolons, but wouldn't the open curly braces also prevent semicolons from being inserted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The action creators are functions. Function bodies are enclosed in curly braces. Arrow functions allow you to return immediately instead of using the return keyword by *omitting* the curly braces that normally surround a function body. However, objects are also surrounded by curly braces. If you leave out the parenthesis, the arrow function believes it is *opening* and *closing* the function, as opposed to *returning an object*.

It believes:

```
const myActionCreator = (value) => {
  type: 'MY_ACTION',
  value
};
```

Means:

```
const myActionCreator = function(value) {
  type: 'MY_ACTION',
  value
};
```

Instead of:

```
const myActionCreator = function(value) {
  return {
    type: 'MY_ACTION',
    value
  };
};
```

To solve this issue, you put parenthesis around the curly braces. Now the arrow function knows it is returning what is inside the parenthesis, as opposed to opening the function body. And inside the parenthesis -- your object.

**This is true for all arrow functions,** not just redux.

Comment: Nice explanation!

Comment: *"Function definitions are enclosed in curly braces."* That makes it sound like you'd have to write `{function foo() {} }`. A better wording would be: *function **bodys** are enclosed in curly braces*.

Comment: You're right. I knew there would be a more accurate term for it. I've updated my answer to use _body_.

Answer (score 2):

Those functions are ecmascript-6's arrow functions and with arrow functions if you want to return an object you have to use `({..})`. If you don't use parentheses and use only the curly ones function sees that like function blocks and can't return an object as intended here.

```
const foo = () => bar;
```

is actually a shorthand for

```
const foo = () => { return bar };
```

We can skip `{}` and `return` part for our shorthand as you can see. We don't need to use a `return` in the shorthand but if we use curly braces as a block, we have to use `return` to inform our function "Here is my return".

So in the shorthand one what if we want to return an object?

```
const foo = () => { object values };
```

Then our function needs a return here, also it sees curly braces as a function block, then we loose our object.

This is why we parenthesize our function body to return an object in the shorthand method.

```
const foo = () => ({ object values });
```

Comment: Indeed, at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions there is an 'Advanced Syntax' section indicating to parenthesize the body of the function to return an object literal.

Comment: Yes, documentation mentions that as you stated.